# Help the grandparents find their password

Tags: code-golf, string

Here's a scenario:
A grandmother and grandfather forget what their GMail password is. They know the word, but can't remember which letters are capitals. 
The challenge is to take a word given and print(stdout) every combination of capital letters possible, essentially "brute-forcing" but only on a given string.

### Example:

`and`  would output

```
and
anD
aNd
aND
And
AnD
ANd
AND
```

### Example:

`ea!`  would output

```
ea!   
Ea!  
EA!  
eA!
```

### Rules

- ASCII characters only
- Input doesn't have to be lowercase
- The order is not important
- Non-alphabetic chars are left alone
- [Standard Loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Any form of input is allowed
- Repetition is ***NOT*** allowed

### Leaderboard Snippet:

```js
function answersUrl(a){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+a+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(a,b){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+b.join(";")+"/comments?page="+a+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(a){answers.push.apply(answers,a.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],a.items.forEach(function(a){a.comments=[];var b=+a.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(b),answers_hash[b]=a}),a.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(a){a.items.forEach(function(a){a.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[a.post_id].comments.push(a)}),a.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(a){return a.owner.display_name}function process(){var a=[];answers.forEach(function(b){var c=b.body;b.comments.forEach(function(a){OVERRIDE_REG.test(a.body)&&(c="<h1>"+a.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var d=c.match(SCORE_REG);d&&a.push({user:getAuthorName(b),size:+d[2],language:d[1],link:b.share_link})}),a.sort(function(a,b){var c=a.size,d=b.size;return c-d});var b={},c=1,d=null,e=1;a.forEach(function(a){a.size!=d&&(e=c),d=a.size,++c;var f=jQuery("#answer-template").html();f=f.replace("{{PLACE}}",e+".").replace("{{NAME}}",a.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",a.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",a.size).replace("{{LINK}}",a.link),f=jQuery(f),jQuery("#answers").append(f);var g=a.language;/<a/.test(g)&&(g=jQuery(g).text()),b[g]=b[g]||{lang:a.language,user:a.user,size:a.size,link:a.link}});var f=[];for(var g in b)b.hasOwnProperty(g)&&f.push(b[g]);f.sort(function(a,b){return a.lang>b.lang?1:a.lang<b.lang?-1:0});for(var h=0;h<f.length;++h){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),g=f[h];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",g.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",g.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",g.size).replace("{{LINK}}",g.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var QUESTION_ID=110455,OVERRIDE_USER=8478,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align: left!important; font-family: sans-serif}#answer-list,#language-list{padding: 10px; width: 290px; float: left}table thead{font-weight: 700}table td{padding: 5px; margin: 0}table tr:nth-child(even){background: #eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr> <td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table></div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr> <td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr> <td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr> <td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You say *print*. Is it allowed to return the result from a function? That's usually permitted here.

Comment: Also, do the output strings have to be unique or could we print all variations of `ea!` twice?

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be in lowercase?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Sorry, I was just going to update to show the current winner

Comment: @GeordieFischer When there is a better answer, you would need to deselect the previous winner's answer. No one wants to see their reputation points go up then down. Anyway, the problem is solved now, so I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to contain at least one letter?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but after outputting three combinations the program halted and I got an SMS, saying I had to stop... ?

Comment: Sorry for dupe.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
żŒsŒpQY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390z9FJxUcnFQRG/v//Xz0xr7g8tcjWxEgdAA)

#### How it works

```
żŒsŒpQY Main link. Argument: s (string)

 Œs     Yield s with swapped case.
ż       Zip s with the result, creating an array of character pairs.
   Œp   Take the Cartesian product.
      Y Join, separating by linefeeds.
     Q  Unique; deduplicate the result.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Bash + GNU utils, 38

```bash
eval echo `sed 's/[a-z]/{\l&,\u&}/gi'`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU1BPzEtRV1BPTVRUt1ZIyedSAILU5Ix8BSUVmDIlhRqFmP@pZYk5EJmE4tQUBfVi/ehE3apY/eqYHDWdmFK1Wv30TPWE/yn5ean/AQ).

The sed expression replaces every letter with `{<LOWER>,<UPPER>}`, where `<LOWER>` and `<UPPER>` are respectively the lower- and upper- case versions of that letter.  These are bash brace expansions which are then expanded - the `eval` ensures this is the last expansion to happen.

Comment: That's clever, but it seems to break if the input contains certain special characters. Not sure if that's a problem.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nicely done

Comment: And the port to Perl (37 bytes) : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#DcrBDYMwDADAP1OYEPECZQDUTSIhtxgaFCWWbV5VZw@874aeSTLM3Pz6Omsq3k1Hrm/QEDmHX8x@nOLlx384JLWFJRUDF4tbYIDzUgOroMQoaAT2JdjSvpPQ04we/qCSNixbR9jf "Perl – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
!tYohZ}&Z*Xu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@69YEpmfEVWrFqUVUfr/v7proqI6AA)

Same idea as Dennis, only less neat, with Luis Mendo's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>99</s> 97 bytes

Returns a space-separated list of words.

```js
f=(s,i)=>--i<1?'':s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c[`to${i&n?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](n*=2),n=1)+' '+f(s,i||n)
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(s,i)=>--i<1?'':s.replace(/[a-z]/gi,c=>c[`to${i&n?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](n*=2),n=1)+' '+f(s,i||n)

console.log(f("and"))
console.log(f("ea!"))
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>115</s> <s>101</s> <s>99</s> <s>102</s> 101 bytes

saved 14 bytes thanks @user63956.

```php
function f($b,$a="
"){$b&a?f($c=substr($b,1),$a.$d=$b[0])|ctype_alpha($d^=" ")&&f($c,$a.$d):print$a;}
```

recursive function, prints the results with a leading newline

**breadown**

```php
function f($b,$a="\n")                          // $b=remaining input, $a= prepared output
{
    // while $b is not empty
    $b&a        # this is not a typo!
        // recurse with $d(=first char of $b) appended to $a
        ?f($c=substr($b,1),$a.$d=$b[0])
        // if $d is letter, recurse with $d (case toggled) appended to $a
            |ctype_alpha($d)&&f($c,$a.$d^=" ")
    // if $b is empty, print $a
    :print$a;
}
```

Comment: You can toggle the case of ASCII letters with `^' '`  and get rid of `*cfirst()` calls.

Comment: Checking if the string is not empty can be written as `a&$b`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 95 bytes (non-recursive)

```bash
s=${1,,}$'
'
s[1]=${s^^}
for((n=${#s};z<n*2**n;)){ echo -n "${s[z/n>>z%n&1]:z++%n:1}";}|sort -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcpLDkAwEADQfU/R@KuK1FJxESFBiNU0MWxac/bq8iXP45A4JSUlOcsZTmoOxmUhdpq7KCAoRtK2B9EKAbosHT/2y/AaeBTmZBsYR5tCpubOVlUKnaJI04fmfnj9eu/dKjf6AQ)

*Note: This solution and the recursive solution below both require bash 4; the ${x,,} and ${x^^} constructs weren't available in bash 3.*

This is quite a bit longer than @DigitalTrauma's solution, but I think it works on all strings, even if they have special characters in them.  For example, with input

```bash
{a,b}
```

this program outputs

```bash
{A,B}
{A,b}
{a,B}
{a,b}
```

as it should.  (@DigitalTrauma's solution, although very ingenious, doesn't work for this input and other similar inputs.)

---

---

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, 88 bytes (recursive)

```bash
[ "$1" ]&&(c=${1:0:1};sed "h;s/^/${c,,}/;p;g;s/^/${c^^}/"<<<`$0 "${1:1}"`|sort -u)||echo
```

This recursive solution works on input `{a,b}` but it has problems with other special characters, for example, input `a/b`.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (Firefox 30-57), 92 bytes

```
f=([c,...a])=>c?[for(l of new Set([c.toLowerCase(),c.toUpperCase()]))for(r of f(a))l+r]:['']
```

Accepts a string or array of characters and returns an array of strings.

Comment: Now that this question has been marked duplicate, I've just discovered that I posted an eerily similar answer to that question...

Answer (score 0):

### C <s>247</s> 229 bytes

```
i,n,j,k,l;f(char *s){l=strlen(s);for(i=0;i<l;i++)s[i]=tolower(s[i]);int v[l];for(i=0;i<pow(2,l);i++){n=i,k=0;for(;n;k++){v[k]=n;n/=2;}for(j=0;j<l;j++){v[j]%=2;if(v[j])s[j]=toupper(s[j]);else s[j]=tolower(s[j]);}printf("%s ",s);}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f(char *s)
{
  int i,num,k,l=strlen(s);
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
     s[i]=tolower(s[i]);

   int v[l];    

   for(i=0;i<pow(2,l);i++)
   {
      num=i,k=0;
      for(;num;k++)
      {
         v[k]=num;
         num/=2;        
      } 

      for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
      {
        v[j]%=2;
        if(v[j])
         s[j]=toupper(s[j]);
        else
         s[j]=tolower(s[j]);

      }
      printf("%s \n",s);       

   } 
}
```

Explanation:

- Accept the character string, convert the string to lowercase.
- Declare integer array of length equal to that of the string.
- Store the numbers from 0 to `2^strlen(s)`in binary form in an `int` array.( For a 3 byte string: 000,001,010...111)
- Depending on if a bit at a position is set or, toggle the case.
- Output the string for every possible combination.

Comment: Macroing strlen would save a bunch of bytes. Or better yet use while(c[i]) (you can assume that the strings are null terminated)